# How to order by use in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-order-by, codeigniter-3

My table data is like that

| ID | NAME | order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | English | 0 |
| 2 | Italian | 1 |
| 3 | Spanish | 2 |
| 4 | Hindi | 1 |
| 5 | Bengali | 3 |
| 6 | Tamil | 2 |

my query

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('languages');
    $this->db->order_by('order','asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

I want data like this order-1,1,2,2,3,0

| ID | NAME | order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Italian | 1 |
| 4 | Hindi | 1 |
| 3 | Spanish | 2 |
| 6 | Tamil | 2 |
| 5 | Bengali | 3 |
| 1 | English | 0 |

Comment: Why set order to 0 if you want it to appear at the end? Have you tried setting it to something like 4 or 10000 or so?

Comment: when insert value oder colunm always 0, next set the order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order = 0  is a boolean that evaluates to 1 when the value is 1 and otherwise 0. The order part orders the rest of the values in ascending order.

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM order_1 
ORDER BY `order`= 0, `order`;
```

See example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/mgIzA2fh)