# SQL query order by two columns

Tags: sql

[image]

**Output looks like: NBH3,A233,HG2233,HG323,B34**

I want Data with latest date will come first and count with all zeros will come last. I tried with Date desc, count desc but didn't received expected result. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please remove unrelated tags. mysql != (ms) sql-server != oracle

Comment: What data type is the column date?

Comment: From your example data, it's unclear what you want to achieve. You don't have any two rows with the same value in the Date column, so the Count sorting criterion would never apply. Please [edit] your question and add the DDL statement for your table, more complete example data and the expected output to turn this into a [MCVE].

Comment: Is (BH123, 10th November, 0) expected to come first or last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correct, the sort criterium with the highest priority for you is this question: Is the value of column `count` `0` or not? Those with `0` should appear last. And then the `date` is the second criterium with lower priority. So you can do following:

```
SELECT
  item, yourdate, count
FROM yourtable
  ORDER BY
    CASE COUNT WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    yourdate DESC;
```

Try out above query on this [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ax7Ju5wV). It is based on your description, but contains some further "test rows" with `item` = `Test123` to show the result of this query in case there are different rows with same `item`, but different `date` and `count` values.

Note: I renamed the `date` column to `yourdate` in this example just to avoid issues. It's recommended to do not use SQL key words as table name or column name.

Another note: This answer assumes the `date` column is of data type `date` (as it should be). If not, you might need to cast it in the query or much better **modify** the table and make it a `date`. Generally, columns should always have the correct data type to keep things easy and clear, so a `date` should be saved in a `date` column.

Answer (score 0):

[image of query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLix8.png)

**This is working for mysql**

> SELECT * FROM `overflow` ORDER BY `Count` = 0 ASC, `Date` DESC

Comment: Could you please edit your answer and add for which DBMS this is a valid syntax and for which not? This is obviously not working on each DBMS, see https://dbfiddle.uk/DPKV4jR8

Comment: @JonasMetzler I think this  syntax applies to MySQL only. I have written an answer some times ago on this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68542904/how-to-order-by-use-in-codeigniter/68543318#68543318